# Variable declared at class level looses it's value while setting it in one method and retriving it from another method

Tags: grails, groovy

Say I have a class with variable `var1`.  I click on a button & it calls `pageLoadMethod()` which loads the page and inside it I set var1 to 10.
Now I click on another button after page is loaded `ajaxMethod()` & try to retrive var1 value but not getting it's value set in 
`pageLoadMethod()` method.

```
    Class MyClass{

    def var1 = 1;

       def pageLoadMethod(){
         var1 = 10;
         ....
      }

       def ajaxMethod(){
         println var1; // prints 1 instead of 10
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The premise of this answer is that MyClass is  a controller, which I assume from the context.**

In Grails the controller instances are by default created for each request - that's why you don't see changed value of var1 in the `ajaxMethod`.

You can make a singleton from the controller by adding this line into it:

```
static scope = "singleton"
```

After this you should see the changed value in `ajaxMethod`.

Another question is if this is a good approach when multiple users can access your controller at the same time - if you want to use the variable to save some state between user's requests, you should rather use session for that..

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `MyClass` is kind of controller. Whats the scope of this controller ? If You want to keep it's state between requests, you should use Session scope.

http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/single.html#controllersAndScopes

Comment: It was default scope of controller so I added the value in session.